# How to extract data from data frame when value of column change

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I want to extract part of the data frame when value change from 0 to 1.

logic1: when value change from 0 to 1, start to save data until value again change to 0. (also points before 1 and after 1)

logic2: when value change from 0 to 1, start to save data until value again change to 0. (don't need to save points before 1 and after 1)

only save data when the first time value of flag change from 0 to 1, after this if again value change from 0 to 1 don't need to do anything

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],'flag':[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]})

Desired output:
df_out_1=pd.DataFrame({'value':[7,8,11,1,15]})

Desired output:
df_out_2=pd.DataFrame({'value':[8,11,1]})
```

Comment: can you elaborate more about the logic ?

Comment: so what is the trigger of this changes ? you can use `df[df['flag'] == 1]` and save it to your desired variable in each trigger.

Comment: @dzakyputra you are talking about simple filter , in this way i will get rows with flag 1, its not my requirement

Answer (score 1):

Idea is get consecutive groups of `1` and `0` consecutive groups to `s`, filter only `1` groups and get first `1` group by compare by minimal value:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
s = df['flag'].ne(df['flag'].shift()).cumsum()
m = s.eq(s[df['flag'].eq(1)].min())

df2 = df.loc[m, ['value']]
print (df2)
   value
3      8
4     11
5      1
```

And then filter values with aff and remove `1` to default `RangeIndex`:

```
df1 = df.loc[(df2.index + 1).union(df2.index - 1), ['value']]
print (df1)
   value
2      7
3      8
4     11
5      1
6     15
```